# How to increase the rotation speed in android?

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I have an image drawable. i rotating the image like a progress bar.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360" android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_white_48" />
```

i want to increase the rotation speed? for that, What attribute i have to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [duration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:duration) and [repeatCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:repeatCount) that you want the animation to run.

Comment: What if the repeatCount should be 0, so that it rotates forever (used for progressBar, in "indeterminateDrawable") ? The duration doesn't seem to do anything in this case...

Answer (score 138):

Setting duration and/or repeat count did not help me with an indeterminate ProgressBar animation.  I had to increase the toDegrees to have it make additional loops:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_indeterminate_progress"
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1080" /> <!--1080 is 3 loops instead of 1 in same amt of time-->
```

Comment: It become skips many degrees at animation repeat when we set it to a value like 0 to non-integer multiple of 360 (e.g. 540) degrees. is there a workaound for this

Comment: Great solution, only this one helped with indeterminate progress.

Answer (score 46):

According to [**this link**](http://codebin.co.uk/blog/custom-indeterminate-progressbar-on-android/):

> The rotation speed of the indeterminate progress bar is fixed at one
>   revolution every 4 seconds, changing the duration attribute in the
>   drawable XML has no effect. If you prefer to speed it up, you can
>   change the toDegrees attribute to multiples of 360:
>
> - 720 makes one turn in 2 seconds
> - 1080 makes one turn in 1.33 seconds
> - 1440 makes one turn in 1 second

In addition, you can just use indeterminateDuration for the ProgressBar.

Answer (score 15):

add in code to **progress.xml**

```
 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="1080" /> <!--1080 is 3 loops instead of 1 in same amt of time-->
```

Comment: Hello, could you include a description of the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
android:duration="required value in ms"
```

Comment: this property is now available in rotate tag

Answer (score 1):

### add in code to progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="1440">
    
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:thicknessRatio="8"
            android:useLevel="false">
    
            <size
                android:width="76dip"
                android:height="76dip" />
    
            <gradient
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="false"
                android:startColor="#FF0000"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:angle="0"/>
    
        </shape>
    
    </rotate>
```