# Android Indeterminate ProgressBar does not spin

Tags: android, progress-bar

Sorry if this has been asked before but I cannot find the answer for this (I have searched!)

I have tried to follow the google/android documentation to make an indeterminate progressbar appear and spin while my app does a lengthy task.

```
protected void readData(final String whatToFind) 
{

    try
    {
        if (whatToFind.length() == 0)
        {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }


        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        m_dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            m_dialog.setTitle("Searching...");
            m_dialog.setMessage("Please wait while searching...");
            m_dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            m_dialog.setCancelable(true); 
            m_dialog.show(); 

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
                {    
                    public void run() 
                    {

                                while (LotsOfWorkGoingOn)  
                                {
                                    // Update the progress bar
                                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                         public void run() {
                                             mProgress.setProgress(m_i); /// vain attempt to make the progressbar spin
                                         }
                                     });                                

                                                         mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                         mProgressText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                         m_dialog.hide();

                                            }

                        });
            }
        }).start();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(LOGid, "Error listing items:" + ex.getStackTrace());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there is an UI blocking issue, you can extend `AsyncTask` and use it in this way:

```
ProgressDialog m_dialog;

protected void readData(final String whatToFind) {

    if (whatToFind.length() == 0) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return;
    }

    m_dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    new LengthyTask().execute();
}

//AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
//Params: type passed in the execute() call, and received in the doInBackground method
//Progress: type of object passed in publishProgress calls
//Result: object type returned by the doInBackground method, and received by onPostExecute()
private class LengthyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // initialize the dialog
        m_dialog.setTitle("Searching...");
        m_dialog.setMessage("Please wait while searching...");
        m_dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        m_dialog.setCancelable(true);
        m_dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // do the hard work here
        // call publishProgress() to make any update in the UI
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // called from publishProgress(), you can update the UI here
        // for example, you can update the dialog progress
        // m_dialog.setProgress(values[0]); --> no apply here, because we made it indeterminate
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // close the dialog
        m_dialog.dismiss();
        //do any other UI related task
    }
}
```

For a more in-depth explanation of `AsyncTask`, read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thanks Chopin, will check it out later - but will accept this answer now

Answer (score 10):

`setProgress` only have effect when the progressbar is not Indeterminate.

Indeterminate means that, it has no progress amount, and it's used when you don't know the amount of progress done/remaining to end the task.

As stated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html):

> A progress bar can also be made indeterminate. In indeterminate mode, the progress bar shows a cyclic animation without an indication of progress. This mode is used by applications when the length of the task is unknown. The indeterminate progress bar can be either a spinning wheel or a horizontal bar.

On the other hand, if you don't even see the progress bar, maybe you have a light background?

Try to set the style attribute to:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
```

Comment: Thanks Chopin, the progressbar appears, the thread executes, but the progressbar does not spin/animate, that's why (out of desperation) I added the "setProgress".

Any idea why it would appear, but not animate the progressbar?

Comment: Are you running this time-consuming task directly on the UI thread? If so, it will block the UI from any animation.

Comment: The task is called from the UI thread allright, but I can't see a way around that as the action is the result of a UI click. I have encased the lengthy task inside:
"new Thread(new Runnable()         {
            public void run()             {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable()                 {    
                    public void run()                     {"
Type structure as per the google documentation...
What is the alternative?

Comment: Oh, I see that in the code. The other way is using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask). I think it's a more clever way. I'll post an example if you need one.

Comment: Thanks Chpoin, I'd really appreciate an example - I've spent hours on this and nothing I have tried has made the progressbar animate.

Comment: @StephenLacey posted an example in a separate answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 9):

In my case i simply forgot that all animations were disable on the device. Nothing blocking or any bad control setting.

Comment: Hahaha this was my case as well

Comment: Even after years of experience you'll always fall with the mist stupid things!

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but for those that landed here trying to make their custom indeterminate `ProgressBar` spin, hopefully this helps you out. Set `android:indeterminateDrawable` not to the actual asset, but to your own custom drawable that ROTATES your asset.

Define res/drawable/progress_indeterminate_custom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <rotate
      android:drawable="@drawable/your_custom_drawable"
      android:fillAfter="true"
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toDegrees="360" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

When the task starts and ends, you can set the visibility of the `ProgressBar` to `VISIBLE` and `GONE` respectively.

If you want to modify the speed of the rotation, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19185350/1221537) says to change the `toDegrees` to multiples of 360 (ie. 720, 1080, etc).

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask should do the trick, but I recommend [Android Annotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/WorkingWithThreads) to make this kind of thing a lot less verbose (and a lot easier).

```
void myMethod() {
    someBackgroundWork("hello", 42);
}
```

The thing to happen in the background:

```
@Background
void someBackgroundWork(String aParam, long anotherParam) {
    [...]
    doInUiThread("hello", 42);
}
```

Which can call something to happen in the UI thread.

```
@UiThread
void doInUiThread(String aParam, long anotherParam) {
    [...]
}
```

Android Annotations is probably worth it for this alone, but there are many other useful Annotations.