# change ProgressBar fps in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I use an `ProgressBar` in xml Android bus is very slow. Optimal is 60fps. Is it possible to change the frame rate or to add custom progress circle with more fps?

```
 <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165938/how-to-increase-the-rotation-speed-in-android

Answer (score 6):

You can modify the duration with:

```
android:indeterminateDuration=<duration in ms>
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#indeterminateDuration

Comment: <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
                    
     android:indeterminateOnly="true"
     android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
     android:indeterminateDuration="3500"

                    android:layout_gravity="center" /> Not work.

Comment: What happen if you set something very low, like 50? (I've never used this attribute)

Comment: same speed with 50 :(, try with imageview and loop(animation rotate 360º) in 60fps :p

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry it didn't help. : /

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Add picture and use animation rotation in 360º:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/resultados_estado_carga_imagen"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/cargador"
  android:layout_gravity="center" />

...

final ImageView resultados_estado_carga_imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resultados_estado_carga_imagen);

RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(360, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(700);

resultados_estado_carga_imagen.startAnimation(anim);
```

Thanks :)