# How to change the speed of ProgressBar in Android using Java?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I have a **ProgressBar** (the round shape one) and it spins very fast, how do I change it to spin at a slower speed?

(It is running indefinitely)

---

Here is my XML of ProgressBar:

```xml
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="710dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:padding="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: you can change interpolator to ease-in or slow-in slow out or something else
it won't change speed but will make it look better in many ways

Comment: Can you share your .xml file please?

Comment: @HalilSahin I have edited the question to include the xml code now

Comment: Please visit this docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar#indeterminateDuration

Answer (score 1):

Add a .xml file under /drawable path, like: `drawable/circular_spinner.xml`
circular_spinner:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="3600"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

Change the `toDegrees` and `duration` to control the speed of the spinning. Then call it in your `progressbar` layout.

```xml
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="710dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:padding="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

See also [change ProgressBar fps in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731932/change-progressbar-fps-in-android):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:indeterminateDuration="1000"
```

Old answer `<rotate android:duration="1000"/>` doesn't work now.